# Custom thread and updating EditText android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler, runnable

I am trying to make an application that transfers a random amount of funds from one bank account to another every second until the funds in the first account drop below 100. I have successfully implemented a thread that does this but I am having great trouble updating the UI EditText fields. It should update every second as the funds get transferred but only updates after the funds have dropped below 100. I believe it has to do with my implementation of the handler and the UI thread is unable to update when my transactionAThread is running. Here is the code for my mainActivity. I can post more code if needed but would prefer not to as this is for class.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button startButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    final EditText a1Text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.a1Text);
    final EditText a2Text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.a2Text);
    final BankAccount b1 = new BankAccount(10000);
    final BankAccount b2 = new BankAccount(10000);
    final int[] x = new int[1];
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    //Set a1Text
    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
    sb1.append("");
    sb1.append(b1.balance);
    String str1 = sb1.toString();
    a1Text.setText(str1);
    //Set a2Text
    StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
    sb2.append("");
    sb2.append(b2.balance);
    String str2 = sb2.toString();
    a2Text.setText(str2);

    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (x[0] == 0){
                x[0] = 1;
                while (b1.balance > 100) {
                    //sleep(1000) in below transactionAThread
                    transactionAThread t1 = new transactionAThread(b1, b2);
                    t1.run();
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override //handler that tries to update UI with no avail
                            public void run() {
                            StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
                            sb1.append("");
                            sb1.append(b1.balance);
                            String str1 = sb1.toString();
                            a1Text.setText(str1);

                            //Set a2Text
                            StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
                            sb2.append("");
                            sb2.append(b2.balance);
                            String str2 = sb2.toString();
                            a2Text.setText(str2);

                        }
                    });

                }

            }

           else {
                x[0] = 0;
            }

        }
    });
}
```

My

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
while (b1.balance > 100) {
    transactionAThread t1 = new transactionAThread(b1, b2);
    t1.run();
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
```

Problems here are many. You are in a tight loop creating a thread each time (you are creating thousands of threads) and also posting a new runnable each time (creating thousands of runnables).

You should only create the thread one time (actually, you should use an `AsyncTask`, but that's another story). And, you should only call `handler.post` from INSIDE the worker thread!

Answer (score 0):

Move the UI code to your work thread. Your code could be modified as following:

```
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (x[0] == 0) {
                    x[0] = 1;

                    transactionAThread t1 = new transactionAThread(b1, b2) {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            super.run();

                            while (b1.balance > 100) {
                                // TODO: transaction. calculate b1 and b2.

                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                 mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                                 @Override //handler that tries to update UI with no avail
                                 public void run() {
                                 StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
                                 sb1.append("");
                                 sb1.append(b1.balance);
                                 String str1 = sb1.toString();
                                 a1Text.setText(str1);

                                 //Set a2Text
                                 StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
                                 sb2.append("");
                                 sb2.append(b2.balance);
                                 String str2 = sb2.toString();
                                 a2Text.setText(str2);

                                 }
                                 });
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    t1.start();
                } else {
                    x[0] = 0;
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: what is the t1.start() method? is that a custom method that I have to create within my transactionAThread class? it does not seem to be built in

Comment: start() is a Thread method that used to run your thread. How did you create transactionAThread? transactionAThread extends Thread{}, right?